# Get documentid of a firestore document in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I have tried to get document id of `firestore` using collection details. But it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 void checkUrl(BuildContext context) async {

        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(widget._shareVideo.videoUrl.toString()));
        // _buildAnimation(context);
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          setState(() {
            isLoading = true;
          });
        }else{
          //doc_id
        }
      }
```

[This is my firestore.I want to get
`aPGzDAIaxJzYOKvpgM3q` thid id using `widget._shareVideo.videoUrl.toString()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGhW5.png)

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant Firestore code, so people can help you. It is unclear how you're using it, or where `uid` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

```
snapshot.data.docs[index].reference.id
```

where snapshot is a `QuerySnapshot`.

Here is an example.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .collection('addresses')
    .get(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      return Text(snapshot.data.docs[0].reference.id.toString());
    }
  }
)
```